# Как в Tomcat 8 задать параметр deployOnStartup?

Tags: java, tomcat

Есть .war файл, который необходимо задеплоить во время старта  томкета. В документации я увидел [это](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic_Application_Deployment) . Если я верно понял,то есть некий Host контейнера, параметры которого можно редактировать и есть параметр deployOnStartup, которому нужно присвоить true,чтобы томкет развернул .war архив при запуске. Однако я так и не понял,где прописаны этот и остальные параметры и как их редактировать... Все это производится на ос Ubuntu

Comment: Если используешь Intellij IDEA то могу в ответы кинуть короткий гайд как это сделать, чем то другим помочь не могу)

Comment: да я пытаюсь руками сконфигурировать это дело,чтобы он при старте распаковал .war архив..но я не отказался бы от гайда.любая информация не бывает лишней)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коротко в скринах

В Intellij в открытом проекте конфигурироем запуск проекта
[image: Конфиг]

Дальше click на ТомКат

[image: Конфиг окно]

И открываеться конфиг окно для ТомКата

[image: ТомКат конифг]

Тут настраеваешь под себя  все(Path to tomcat, ip, etc) и в Deplyment, там будет опция деплоая в Jar или War.

При сборке проекта томкат запустит ваш проект.

Удачи!
ПС привет из Кишинева ( :

Comment: спасибо.и тебе привет)из Кишинева)